# Оптимизация запроса Oracle

Tags: oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста разобраться с запросом, так-как я только учусь, то инетересно мнение и совет знающих людей, по оптимизации моего sql запроса, в чем я допустил ошибки,сам запрос выглядит так :

```
select nkl, tzav, Psum,Lsum,Ltl, Lth,nv,nvp
from zxp.valpr where (nkl,tzav) in (select nkl, MAX(tzav) from zxp.valpr where tviv is null and pvn=0 and rop=1 group by nkl ) AND pvn=0 and rop=1
order by nkl
```

Всем большое спасибо за помощь, и совет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал как минимум избавиться от подзапроса и реализовать его через `inner join` (на таблицах с несколькими десятками миллионами записей разница по времени будет в несколько раз, если не десятков раз):

```
select t1.nkl, t1.tzav, t1.Psum, t1.Lsum, t1.Ltl, t1.Lth, t1.nv, t1.nvp
from zxp.valpr t1 inner join (select nkl, MAX(tzav) as maxi
                              from zxp.valpr
                              where tviv is null
                                    and pvn = 0
                                    and rop = 1
                              group by nkl) t2
              on t1.nkl = t2.nkl and t1.tzav = t2.maxi
where 1=1
      and t1.pvn = 0
      and t1.rop = 1
order by t1.nkl
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но при запросе получил ошибку: **DBCException: SQL Error [918] [42000]: ORA-00918: столбец определен неоднозначно
  java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00918: столбец определен неоднозначно** В чем проблема ?

Comment: @Ethernets поправил

Comment: Большое спасибо, не подскажите почему такой вариант выполниться быстрее ? и по какому учебнику можно научиться так же как вы формировать запросы ? еще раз спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets этот учебник - работа) мне пояснили это еще на этапе собеседований - когда идет join, то формируется таблица из двух таблиц и уже идет работа с ней, а когда подзапрос - он каждый раз вызывается на каждой строке (могу ошибаться с нюансами). При работе с большими таблицами преобразование подзапросов в join сокращало порой время с часу до 5-10 минут. Из учебников могу лишь sql-tutorial.ru посоветовать.

Comment: Еще раз большое вам спасибо.

Comment: @Denis Подзапросы типа `in()` без использования внутри данных из внешнего запроса выполняются в Oracle один раз и ни чем не отличаются от join. Хотя могут быть различные нюансы как ускоряющие так и замедляющие выборку, в каждом конкретном случае только сравнение плана выполнения на требуемой версии Oracle может показать различны ли они и что быстрее